# Task List with parameters

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, async-await, dotnet-httpclient

I'm needing to create a list of tasks to execute a routine that takes one parameter and then wait for those tasks to complete before continuing with the rest of the program code. Here is an example:

```
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
foreach (string URL in LIST_URL_COLLECTION)
{
    tasks[i] = Task.Factory.StartNew(
        GoToURL(URL)
        );
}
//wait for them to finish
Console.WriteLine("Done");
```

I've have googled and searched this site but I just keep hitting a dead end, I did this once but can't remember how.

Comment: Well what have you looked at in the `Task` type? Does it have anything which says "waits for the task to finish"? (You might also want to look at `Task.WhenAll` and `Task.WaitAll`, but my point is that you shouldn't have reached a dead end already if you've read the `Task` documentation.)

Comment: i've spent hours trying to figure this thing out.. some people pick this stuff up easier than others.. i've read so many half answers i just want to get a complete answer just for someone to show me how it's done

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Task Parallel Library` exposes a convinent way to asynchronously wait for the completion of all tasks via the [`Task.WhenAll`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method. The method returns a `Task` by itself which is awaitable and should be awaited:

```
public async Task QueryUrlsAsync()
{
    var urlFetchingTasks = ListUrlCollection.Select(url => Task.Run(url));
    await Task.WhenAll(urlFetchingTasks);
    Console.WriteLine("Done");
}
```

Note that in order to `await`, your method must be marked with the `async` modifier in the method signature and return either a `Task` (if it has no return value) or a `Task<T>` (if it does have a return value, which type is `T`).

As a side note, your method looks like it's fetching urls, which i am assuming is generating a web request to some endpoint. In order to do that, there's no need to use extra threads via `Task.Factory.StartNew` or `Task.Run`, as these operations are *naturally asynchronous*. You should look into [`HttpClient`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) as a starting point. For example, your method could look like this:

```
public async Task QueryUrlsAsync()
{
    var urlFetchingTasks = ListUrlCollection.Select(url => 
                           {
                               var httpClient = new HttpClient();
                               return httpClient.GetAsync(url);
                           });

    await Task.WhenAll(urlFetchingTasks);
    Console.WriteLine("Done");
}
```